# How to apply fixture from conftest.py to inner folders only

Tags: python, pytest, conftest

I have a fixture that located in conftest.py.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True) 
def my_fixture():
    """
    Some useful code
    """
```

The structure is like below:

```
tests
 |
 |--first_folder
 |   |--__init__.py
 |   |--test_first_1.py
 |   |--test_first_2.py
 |   
 |--second_folder
 |   |--__init__.py
 |   |--test_second_1.py
 |
 |--__init__.py   
 |--conftest.py
 |--test_common_1.py
```

I want that fixture to be auto-used in **inner folders** test scripts only: in *test_first_1.py*, *test_first_2.py*, *test_second_1.py*, but NOT in *test_common_1.py*.

I can create conftest with that fixture in each inner folder, but I don't want to duplicate the code

Is there any way to apply fixture from conftest to test scripts from inner folders and ignore it in common folder test scripts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@lmiguelvargasf [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62780389/how-to-apply-fixture-from-conftest-py-to-inner-folders-only/62783671#62783671) (+1) pointed me in the right direction and using `request` I solved the issue as below:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def my_fixture(request):
    if request.config.invocation_dir.basename != 'tests':
        """
        Some useful code
        """
```

This fixture will be applied only to test-scripts from inner folders as **invocation folder name is not equal to 'tests'**

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution, is you do not want to change the structure of your folders, is that you use the `request` object in your fixture to check the markers used on the test, so you do anything if a specific marker is set:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True) 
def my_fixture(request):
    """
    Some useful code
    """
    if 'noautofixt' in request.keywords:
        return
    # more code
```

Then mark your tests as follows:

```py
@pytest.mark.noautofixt
def test_no_running_my_fixture():
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this by moving the folders 'first folder' and 'second folder' to a new folder and have a conftest.py file in that new folder. Like this -

```
tests
 |
 |--new folder
 |  |--first_folder
 |  |  |--__init__.py
 |  |  |--test_first_1.py
 |  |  |--test_first_2.py
 |  |
 |  |--second_folder
 |  |  |--__init__.py
 |  |  |--test_second_1.py
 |  |--conftest.py
 |
 |--__init__.py   
 |--conftest.py
 |--test_common_1.py
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention that I cannot change folder structure as we should stick to TestRail test cases structure

Answer (score 2):

If you want to autouse a top-level conftest fixture for **only a subset** of your test modules, the [guidance](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#use-fixtures-in-classes-and-modules-with-usefixtures) is to make use of the global variable `pytestmark` (reference: [pytestmark](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#globalvar-pytestmark); tutorial: [Marking whole classes or modules](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/markers.html#scoped-marking)).

In your case, you'll want to disable `autouse` for your fixture defined in `tests/conftest.py`:

```py
# tests/conftest.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='module') 
def my_fixture():
    """
    Some useful code
    """
```

Then in whatever module you'd like to enable autouse of it, set the global variable `pytestmark` e.g.

```py
# tests/first_folder/test_first_1.py
import pytest

pytestmark = pytest.mark.usefixtures('my_fixture')

def test_first_feature():
    result = something(my_fixture)  # autouse of my_fixture
    assert result == expected
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is not an option since with that approach I'll need to add the same code to each inner-folder test-script while as I said I don't want code duplicating